# Is there a function for adding a new node and wire it via dashboard?

Tags: node-red

I want to create a dashboard that shows me a chart with some temperature sensors, but I want to be able to add new sensors, that means I need to add more mqtt nodes that receive the information from the sensors, so I want to call a function that can add new nodes and fill in that information.

Here's my flow:

```
[
    {
        "disabled": false,
        "id": "8de11c1b.d1381",
        "info": "En este ejemplo veremos como hacer publish y suscribed un esp8266\n",
        "label": "ESP8266 mqtt example",
        "type": "tab"
    },
    {
        "active": true,
        "complete": "payload",
        "console": false,
        "id": "743d14f5.c455ec",
        "name": "",
        "targetType": "msg",
        "tosidebar": true,
        "tostatus": false,
        "type": "debug",
        "wires": [],
        "x": 550,
        "y": 140,
        "z": "8de11c1b.d1381"
    },
    {
        "broker": "99ab1fe8.351c",
        "datatype": "utf8",
        "id": "331b366d.b09c8a",
        "name": "espClient",
        "qos": "0",
        "topic": "Datalogger/Sensor1/Temperatura",
        "type": "mqtt in",
        "wires": [
            [
                "25f4bc93.5079a4"
            ]
        ],
        "x": 80,
        "y": 60,
        "z": "8de11c1b.d1381"
    },
    {
        "id": "2e0aed2b.1f5392",
        "influxdb": "b162be8e.9a228",
        "measurement": "Datalogger",
        "name": "espClient",
        "precision": "",
        "retentionPolicy": "",
        "type": "influxdb out",
        "wires": [],
        "x": 560,
        "y": 200,
        "z": "8de11c1b.d1381"
    },
    {
        "func": "//msg.payload = Number(msg.payload);\n//return msg;\n\nmsg.payload={\n Temp1: Number(msg.payload)\n // Num2: parseFloat((Math.random()*10).toFixed(0))\n}\nreturn msg;",
        "id": "25f4bc93.5079a4",
        "name": "String2Number",
        "noerr": 0,
        "outputs": 1,
        "type": "function",
        "wires": [
            [
                "6babeab6.ef08c4"
            ]
        ],
        "x": 240,
        "y": 60,
        "z": "8de11c1b.d1381"
    },
    {
        "broker": "2bd5e6a3.18b54a",
        "datatype": "utf8",
        "id": "1fb3b52c.4a48fb",
        "name": "espClient2",
        "qos": "0",
        "topic": "Datalogger/Sensor2/Temperatura",
        "type": "mqtt in",
        "wires": [
            [
                "aeedb7d8.8b7158"
            ]
        ],
        "x": 80,
        "y": 120,
        "z": "8de11c1b.d1381"
    },
    {
        "func": "//msg.payload = Number(msg.payload);\n//return msg;\n\nmsg.payload={\n Temp2: Number(msg.payload)\n // Num2: parseFloat((Math.random()*10).toFixed(0))\n}\nreturn msg;",
        "id": "aeedb7d8.8b7158",
        "name": "String2Number",
        "noerr": 0,
        "outputs": 1,
        "type": "function",
        "wires": [
            [
                "743d14f5.c455ec",
                "2e0aed2b.1f5392"
            ]
        ],
        "x": 240,
        "y": 120,
        "z": "8de11c1b.d1381"
    },
    {
        "func": "//msg.payload = Number(msg.payload);\n//return msg;\n\nmsg.payload={\n Temp3: Number(msg.payload)\n // Num2: parseFloat((Math.random()*10).toFixed(0))\n}\nreturn msg;",
        "id": "956da7ee.eab5e8",
        "name": "String2Number",
        "noerr": 0,
        "outputs": 1,
        "type": "function",
        "wires": [
            [
                "743d14f5.c455ec",
                "2e0aed2b.1f5392"
            ]
        ],
        "x": 240,
        "y": 180,
        "z": "8de11c1b.d1381"
    },
    {
        "func": "//msg.payload = Number(msg.payload);\n//return msg;\n\nmsg.payload={\n Temp4: Number(msg.payload)\n // Num2: parseFloat((Math.random()*10).toFixed(0))\n}\nreturn msg;",
        "id": "9bc165af.4a87e8",
        "name": "String2Number",
        "noerr": 0,
        "outputs": 1,
        "type": "function",
        "wires": [
            [
                "743d14f5.c455ec"
            ]
        ],
        "x": 240,
        "y": 240,
        "z": "8de11c1b.d1381"
    },
    {
        "broker": "93b50fd3.02468",
        "datatype": "utf8",
        "id": "61eccc22.ee5ce4",
        "name": "espClient3",
        "qos": "0",
        "topic": "Datalogger/Sensor3/Temperatura",
        "type": "mqtt in",
        "wires": [
            [
                "956da7ee.eab5e8"
            ]
        ],
        "x": 80,
        "y": 180,
        "z": "8de11c1b.d1381"
    },
    {
        "broker": "f8c54557.6bbb98",
        "datatype": "utf8",
        "id": "33d1b802.4b9ff8",
        "name": "espClient4",
        "qos": "0",
        "topic": "Datalogger/Sensor4/Temperatura",
        "type": "mqtt in",
        "wires": [
            [
                "9bc165af.4a87e8"
            ]
        ],
        "x": 80,
        "y": 240,
        "z": "8de11c1b.d1381"
    },
    {
        "broker": "b71e7edb.a0b15",
        "datatype": "utf8",
        "id": "11231c0b.850554",
        "name": "espClient5",
        "qos": "0",
        "topic": "Datalogger/Sensor5/Temperatura",
        "type": "mqtt in",
        "wires": [
            [
                "4f9f9174.18b9f"
            ]
        ],
        "x": 80,
        "y": 300,
        "z": "8de11c1b.d1381"
    },
    {
        "func": "//msg.payload = Number(msg.payload);\n//return msg;\n\nmsg.payload={\n Temp5: Number(msg.payload)\n // Num2: parseFloat((Math.random()*10).toFixed(0))\n}\nreturn msg;",
        "id": "4f9f9174.18b9f",
        "name": "String2Number",
        "noerr": 0,
        "outputs": 1,
        "type": "function",
        "wires": [
            [
                "2e0aed2b.1f5392"
            ]
        ],
        "x": 240,
        "y": 300,
        "z": "8de11c1b.d1381"
    },
    {
        "drop": false,
        "id": "6babeab6.ef08c4",
        "name": "",
        "nbRateUnits": "1",
        "pauseType": "delay",
        "randomFirst": "1",
        "randomLast": "5",
        "randomUnits": "seconds",
        "rate": "1",
        "rateUnits": "second",
        "timeout": "2",
        "timeoutUnits": "seconds",
        "type": "delay",
        "wires": [
            [
                "743d14f5.c455ec",
                "2e0aed2b.1f5392"
            ]
        ],
        "x": 400,
        "y": 60,
        "z": "8de11c1b.d1381"
    },
    {
        "broker": "7d36be02.d2d36",
        "datatype": "utf8",
        "id": "2c2860f1.c501d",
        "name": "espClient6",
        "qos": "0",
        "topic": "Datalogger/Sensor6/Temperatura",
        "type": "mqtt in",
        "wires": [
            [
                "cf399c6.ff3da6"
            ]
        ],
        "x": 80,
        "y": 360,
        "z": "8de11c1b.d1381"
    },
    {
        "func": "//msg.payload = Number(msg.payload);\n//return msg;\n\nmsg.payload={\n Temp6: Number(msg.payload)\n // Num2: parseFloat((Math.random()*10).toFixed(0))\n}\nreturn msg;",
        "id": "cf399c6.ff3da6",
        "name": "String2Number",
        "noerr": 0,
        "outputs": 1,
        "type": "function",
        "wires": [
            [
                "2e0aed2b.1f5392",
                "743d14f5.c455ec"
            ]
        ],
        "x": 260,
        "y": 360,
        "z": "8de11c1b.d1381"
    },
    {
        "birthPayload": "",
        "birthQos": "0",
        "birthTopic": "",
        "broker": "192.168.1.13",
        "cleansession": true,
        "clientid": "espClient",
        "closePayload": "",
        "closeQos": "0",
        "closeTopic": "",
        "compatmode": true,
        "id": "99ab1fe8.351c",
        "keepalive": "60",
        "name": "espClient",
        "port": "1883",
        "type": "mqtt-broker",
        "usetls": false,
        "willPayload": "",
        "willQos": "0",
        "willTopic": "",
        "z": ""
    },
    {
        "database": "Temperatura",
        "hostname": "127.0.0.1",
        "id": "b162be8e.9a228",
        "name": "",
        "port": "8086",
        "protocol": "http",
        "tls": "",
        "type": "influxdb",
        "usetls": false,
        "z": ""
    },
    {
        "birthPayload": "",
        "birthQos": "0",
        "birthTopic": "",
        "broker": "192.168.1.13",
        "cleansession": true,
        "clientid": "espClient2",
        "closePayload": "",
        "closeQos": "0",
        "closeTopic": "",
        "compatmode": true,
        "id": "2bd5e6a3.18b54a",
        "keepalive": "60",
        "name": "espClient2",
        "port": "1883",
        "type": "mqtt-broker",
        "usetls": false,
        "willPayload": "",
        "willQos": "0",
        "willTopic": "",
        "z": ""
    },
    {
        "birthPayload": "",
        "birthQos": "0",
        "birthTopic": "",
        "broker": "192.168.1.13",
        "cleansession": false,
        "clientid": "espClient3",
        "closePayload": "",
        "closeQos": "0",
        "closeTopic": "",
        "compatmode": true,
        "id": "93b50fd3.02468",
        "keepalive": "60",
        "name": "espClient3",
        "port": "1883",
        "type": "mqtt-broker",
        "usetls": false,
        "willPayload": "",
        "willQos": "0",
        "willTopic": "",
        "z": ""
    },
    {
        "birthPayload": "",
        "birthQos": "0",
        "birthTopic": "",
        "broker": "192.168.1.13",
        "cleansession": true,
        "clientid": "espClient4",
        "closePayload": "",
        "closeQos": "0",
        "closeTopic": "",
        "compatmode": true,
        "id": "f8c54557.6bbb98",
        "keepalive": "60",
        "name": "espClient4",
        "port": "1883",
        "type": "mqtt-broker",
        "usetls": false,
        "willPayload": "",
        "willQos": "0",
        "willTopic": "",
        "z": ""
    },
    {
        "birthPayload": "",
        "birthQos": "0",
        "birthTopic": "",
        "broker": "192.168.1.13",
        "cleansession": true,
        "clientid": "espClient5",
        "closePayload": "",
        "closeQos": "0",
        "closeTopic": "",
        "compatmode": true,
        "id": "b71e7edb.a0b15",
        "keepalive": "60",
        "name": "espClient5",
        "port": "1883",
        "type": "mqtt-broker",
        "usetls": false,
        "willPayload": "",
        "willQos": "0",
        "willTopic": "",
        "z": ""
    },
    {
        "birthPayload": "",
        "birthQos": "0",
        "birthTopic": "",
        "broker": "localhost",
        "cleansession": true,
        "clientid": "espclient6",
        "closePayload": "",
        "closeQos": "0",
        "closeTopic": "",
        "compatmode": true,
        "id": "7d36be02.d2d36",
        "keepalive": "60",
        "name": "espClient6",
        "port": "1883",
        "type": "mqtt-broker",
        "usetls": false,
        "willPayload": "",
        "willQos": "0",
        "willTopic": "",
        "z": ""
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is nothing directly exposed to a node running in a flow that will let you edit the flow.

The only option is to use the [Admin API](https://nodered.org/docs/api/admin/) via HTTP to retrieve the JSON representing the flow, edit it to include the new nodes and then repost it back to the API hence redeploying the flow with the adjustments.

This is a nontrivial set of tasks, but if you search on https://flows.nodered.org I think there are some examples.